# Plotting the solutions of the equation $e^{-z}=z$ in the complex plane

Tags: plotting, equation-solving, complex, intersection

I would like to plot in the complex plane the solutions of the equation
$$e^{-z}=z.$$

I tried this:
I took $z=a+ib$ and took the real and imaginary part of the equation:

```
ContourPlot[{a == E^-a Cos[-b], b == E^-a Sin[-b]}, {a, -10, 5}, {b, -10, 10}]
```

[image]

So the intersections of the curves are the solutions to the equation (we notice there's only one real solution).

**I have two questions:**

1. Is there a way to plot the solutions of the equation by showing only the solutions as dots (without showing the curves)?
2. Is there a way to do this just by plugging directly the complex equation $e^{-z}=z$ without translating it to real and imaginary parts?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

We can use  `MeshFunction` in `ComplexContourPlot`.

```
Clear[f];
f[z_] = Exp[-z] - z;
ComplexContourPlot[{Re[f[z]] == 0}, {z, -20 - 20 I, 20 + 20 I}, 
 MeshFunctions -> {Im[f[#]] &}, Mesh -> {{{0}}}, 
 MeshStyle -> Directive[{PointSize[Large], Red}], ContourStyle -> None]
```

[image]

```
Clear[f, fig1, fig2];
f[z_] = Exp[-z] - z;
fig1 = ComplexContourPlot[{Re[f[z]] == 0}, {z, -20 - 20 I, 20 + 20 I},
    MeshFunctions -> {Im[f[#]] &}, Mesh -> {{{0}}}, 
   MeshStyle -> Directive[{PointSize[Large], Red}], 
   ContourStyle -> Brown];
fig2 = ComplexContourPlot[{Im[f[z]] == 0}, {z, -20 - 20 I, 20 + 20 I},
    MeshFunctions -> {Re[f[#]] &}, Mesh -> {{{0}}}, 
   MeshStyle -> Directive[{PointSize[Large], Red}], 
   ContourStyle -> Cyan];
Show[fig1, fig2]
```

[image]

Compare with the approach which use `NSolve`.

```
roots = NSolve[{Exp[-z] - z == 0, -20 <= Re[z] <= 20, -20 <= Im[z] <= 
     20}];
ListPlot[ReIm[z] /. roots, 
 PlotStyle -> Directive[{PointSize[Large], Red}], 
 PlotRange -> {{-20, 20}, {-20, 20}}, AspectRatio -> Automatic]
```

[image]

**Appendix**

For another function,`NSolve` missing some roots.

```
Clear[f, fig1, fig2];
f[z_] = Sin[z + Sin[z + Sin[z]]] - Cos[z + Cos[z + Cos[z]]];
fig1 = ComplexContourPlot[{Re[f[z]] == 0, 
    Im[f[z]] == 0}, {z, -5 - 4 I, 5 + 4 I}, PlotPoints -> 100, 
   ContourStyle -> {Directive[Brown, Thin], Directive[Cyan, Thin]}, 
   ImageSize -> Full];
roots = NSolve[{f[z] == 0, -5 <= Re[z] <= 5, -4 <= Im[z] <= 4}];
fig2 = ListPlot[ReIm[z] /. roots, 
   PlotStyle -> Directive[{PointSize[Small], Red}], 
   PlotRange -> {{-5, 5}, {-4, 4}}, AspectRatio -> Automatic];
Show[fig1, fig2, ImageSize -> Full]
```

[image]

Answer (score 3):

Amplifying on answer by Michael Seifert

```
Clear["Global`*"]

sol = Simplify[Reduce[E^-z == z, z], 
   C[1] ∈ Integers] /. {Equal :> Rule, C[1] :> c}

(* z -> ProductLog[c, 1] *)

roots = Table[z /. sol, {c, -5, 5}];

ListPlot[ReIm@roots]
```

[image]

Answer (score 2):

I believe that your solutions are the values of the [Lambert W-function](https://en.m.wikipedia.org/wiki/Lambert_W_function) at 1:
$$
z=W_k(1). $$
The index $k$ tells you which of the (infinitely many) branches of the function you're on.

In Mathematica, this function is implemented as [`ProductLog`;](https://reference.wolfram.com/language/ref/ProductLog.html) so `ProductLog[k,1]` should produce the desired intersection points for various integer values of `k`.